# Why this systemctl isn't starting?

Tags: bash, systemd, services, startup, systemctl

It's on Debian 11. The file PwOn.service:

```
[Unit]

Description=Send a message with a telegram bot 
After=network.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/JubiBotStartup.sh

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With the bash script JubiBotStartup.sh being

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="randomToken"
ID="11111111"
DT=$(date +'+%d-%m-%Y')
HR=$(date +'+%H:%M:%S')
MSG="System powered on $DT , $HR"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage"
curl -s -X POST $URL -d chat_id=$ID -d text="$MSG"
```

I've enabled the service, and so it appears like that when I put the command
systemctl status.
When I start the service with 'systemctl start PwOn.service' it works correctly.

However, it does not work when the system powers on or restarts, and checking its status shows the following:

```
PwOn.service - Send a message with a telegram bot 
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/PwOn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-07 04:22:37 CET; 21min ago
    Process: 474 ExecStart=/usr/bin/JubiBotStartup.sh (code=exited, status=6)
   Main PID: 474 (code=exited, status=6)
        CPU: 129ms

Mar 07 04:22:36 debian systemd[1]: Started Send a message with a telegram bot 
Mar 07 04:22:37 debian systemd[1]: PwON.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=6/NOTCONFIGURED
Mar 07 04:22:37 debian systemd[1]: PwOn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
~
```

Comment: I'd read [this](https://systemd.io/NETWORK_ONLINE/) - it may provide some useful insight into your issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure a unit runs after the network is online, you need to list [`network-online.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network-online.target) in *both* `Wants=` and `After=`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Send a message with a telegram bot 
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

Currently, your unit is running during network bring-up, and `curl` fails because it can’t resolve the target host (which is what its exit code 6 indicates).